# Push Notifications not FULLY working unless tethered to Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

This has obviously been asked multiple times but I can't seem to get any of the proposed solutions working.

Push notifs work when tethered to xcode. Untethered, I get the push notification itself  but none of the delegate methods are called which results in not being able to increment badge count.

I also can't get silent notifications working on untethered as well. I use silent notifications to clear a notification with a given condition.

I've tried allowing background mode in plist, changing priorities, having an empty body. I've made sure that the device background refresh is on and that notifs are fully on. I've tried a ton more things that I can't remember off the top of my head. Nothing seems to work. I added a badge increment in every one of the push notif delegate methods and it seems none of them get called.

Here is the .js code snippet for regular notif

```js
message1 = {
  notification: {
    title: "stackOverFlowTitle",
    body: "stackOverFlowBody"
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps : {
        "content-available": 1,
        "sound": "default",
        "priority" : 10
      },
      data: {
      //     collection: 'TestCollection',
      //     document: change.after.ref.id,
        timePushed: timePushed,
        alertOn: alertOn,
        readNotification: readNotification,
        eventKey: eventKey
      }
    },
    headers: {
      "apns-expiration": "4"
    }
  },
  topic: topic
};
```

Here is the .js code snippet for silent notif

```js
var message2 = {
  notification: {
    body: ""
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {  
      aps: {
        "content-available": 1,
        "priority" : 10
      },
      data: {
        alertOn: alertOn,
        eventKey: eventKey
      }
    },
    headers: {
      "apns-expiration": "4"
    }
  },
  topic: topic
};
```

Anyone have any potential solutions I haven't mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I changed silent notif priority to 5 and that helped (for this post) :D

Comment: please write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html), when non-zero the `apns-expiration` represents a unix timestamp. By setting it to 4, you're telling APNs to expire the notification at 1970-01-01 00:00:04.